# Tomcat 6 Web Application Eating Up Memory Over Time

Tags: java, memory, grails, monitoring, tomcat6

I have a Grails application that is deployed on a Tomcat 6 server. The application runs fine for a while ( a day or two), but slowly eats up more and more memory over time until it grinds to a halt and then surpasses the maximum value. Once I restart the container, everything is fine. I have been verifying this with the grails JavaMelody plugin as well as the Application Info plugin, but I need help in determining what I should be looking for.

It sounds like an application leak, but to my knowledge there is no access to any unmanaged resources. Also, the Hibernate cache seems to be in check. It looks like if I run the garbage collector I get a decent chunk of memory back, but I don't know how to do this sustainably.

So:

- How can I use these (or other) monitoring tools to figure out where the problem is?
- Is there any other advice that could help me?

Thanks so much.

**EDIT**

I am using Grails 1.3.7 and I am using the Quartz plugin.

Comment: Are you using the Quartz plugin? Also, what version of Grails are you using?

Comment: @Joshua Moore - See my edits. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. Using Grails 1.3.6 with Quartz (although I'm not sure that is the actual problem). Though I need to restart every few weeks so my problem is not that imminent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the VisualVM application in the Oracle JDK to attach to the Tomcat instance while running (if using Oracle JVM already) to inspect what goes on.  The memory profiler can tell you quite a bit and point you in the right direction.  You most likely look for either objects that grow or types of objects that get allocated more and more.

If you need more than the free VisualVM application can tell you, a commercial profiler may be useful.

Comment: Perhaps, but not as easily.  You need to configure the Tomcat JVM to expose JMX ports.

Comment: Is it possible it has to do with the Database Connection Pool? I ran the app locally but it did not exhibit the same problem in the same timeframe. I think it may be because I only had 1 connection open to it, where as the production app has many. The production application has many `TP-Processor` threads whereas the local one I tested on only has a couple. Could this be related? Thanks.

Comment: Could be.  To be certain you need to profile.  If you cannot use VisualVM look into getting hprof data for remote analysis.

Comment: I am trying - couldn't see much from VisualVM, but am now trying to setup `Yourkit` remotely but am running into problems (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396089/yourkit-profile-on-remote-grails-app).  I'll take a look at hprof. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your usage of Quartz it may be directly related to [a know memory leak with the Quartz plugin](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPQUARTZ-32?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3achangehistory-tabpanel) with persistence and thread-local. You may want to double check and see if this applies to your situation.

Comment: Thank you for this insight into Quartz. It wasn't the issue but may be helpful in the future.