# YourKit Profile On Remote Grails App

Tags: grails, ubuntu, tomcat6, profiler, yourkit

I am trying to track down a memory leak that I am having with a Grails application and am using the Yourkit Profiler, but am running into a problem.

I have the Grails application running in Tomcat6 on the Production server and have unpacked the YourKit profiler and ran it [according to the documentation](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/95/help/attach_wizard.jsp) using `sudo bin/yjp.sh -attach`, but I am getting the error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.yourkit.Main$2.run(a:19)
Caused by: com.yourkit.runtime.PresentableException: com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
    at com.yourkit.ui.s.n.a(a:170)
    at com.yourkit.ui.s.n.a(a:176)
    at com.yourkit.ui.s.j.a(a:250)
    at com.yourkit.c.do(a:73)
    at com.yourkit.Main0.entry(a:274)
    ... 5 more
```

I am using YourKit v10 and am on an Ubuntu 11.04 server. Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you are running the Yourkit locally and your Tomcat is running on a remote Ubuntu. Does the Yourkit show the running `PID` and you able to select it before the error?

Comment: @JoseK - I haven't even opened Yourkit locally yet. I am just trying to run the command line on the server. Yes, I can see the running PID and select it. This is when I get the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I had to run as the user running the container. Changing `sudo bin/yjp.sh -attach` to `sudo -u tomcat6 bin/yjp.sh -attach` worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the Attach API working before you can continue:

```
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
```

See the JVisualVM FAQ - their troubleshooting can be used here too.

Comment: Sorry to be so annoying and ignorant. Can you point me in the right direction (in terms of a URL)? I am looking here http://visualvm.java.net/troubleshooting.html but do not see what I am looking for. Hell, I don't even really know what I am looking for. Also, is it possible that I need to run the profiler as the same user that is running the web app? Some people seemed to get the exception when this was the case. I tried running the profiler as the `tomcat6` user, but I don't know how to authenticate as that user. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like it was the fact that I was running as the wrong user. I am still interested in your answer though.